Hide numbers from dialed list after call from react native app
Hello everyone it is possible to hide our contacts from dialed list after call because we are making leads related projects and we don't want to share our leads contact to caller.
We want to hide our numbers from dialed list because our numbers are important and may be expensive numbers in future.
